# Ubuntu alongside Windows 8

Tags: installation, boot, windows-8, boot-partition

I already installed Ubuntu on my Laptop -it is an Hp1000 Notebook PC with windows 8 on it so i installed ubuntu alongside windows 8- I went through all the installation process and it displayed a message telling that the intallation was completed and that i needed to reboot my computer. I did it and it just went into Windows 8 OS, however it created the partition for ubuntu but when i try to open it on windows it tells me that the partition is corrupted. Why does the Ubuntu OS doesn't appear?

Answer (score 0):

Windows can not open Extfs partitions, only fat and ntfs. So in Windows, you can not see any file on the Ubuntu partition. However, in Ubuntu, you can open most of partitions types, and so you can see the Windows files.

If you don't have the Grub menu at startup to choose between Ubuntu and Windows, the Ubuntu installer was not able to write the bootloader in the MBR. It may be because of the UEFI bios. You may find the solution here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI