# Install Ubuntu 13.04 alongside Windows 8

Tags: installation, grub2, dual-boot, 13.04, windows-8

I want Windows 8 64bit (system-builders) and Ubuntu Linux 13.04 on different partitions on the same drive in my new self-built machine. I've previously been using only Ubuntu 12.04LTS and no once my Win8 DVD came from MS, I want to upgrade to 13.04 anyway. I am already completely backed up and ready to migrate, but I don't want to run into bootloader or restrictedboot problems as I keep reading about online.

What do I have to do to make them play well and boot? I'm supposed to install Ubuntu first, right? What else?

I found a bunch of tutorials, but they all want me to use EasyBCD (http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) but that isn't FOSS, and I would much rather use open source stuff to boot my open source OS...

I've read through a bunch of posts similar to:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/260690/install-windows-8-alongside-with-ubuntu
[Ubuntu alongside Windows 8](https://askubuntu.com/questions/268146/ubuntu-alongside-windows-8)

Thanks

Comment: Did you also read: http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system Note to anyone marking this as duplicate that this could actually not be one because the user actually did research other questions, this is why I am first asking the user if he/she did check this link out thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

Install your Windows 8, then using the USB or DVD for Ubuntu 13.04, install 13.04. You will have the option of installing them alongside each other, use that option. Afterwards, when you boot you will get a boot menu asking which OS you want to boot to...

I use a dual boot on one of my machines, Mint 14.1 and Ubuntu 13.04. I get people set up in either one depending on the person and I have to be able to refer to either while teaching the systems. My main machine uses Ubuntu 12.04...