# Installing Ubuntu on a laptop with malfunctioning windows

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation, uefi

I am trying to install Ubuntu on a laptop, that won't boot Windows, it always just asks for reboot. So I decided to install Ubuntu instead and get rid of windows entirely. I started the installation and chose something else for partitioning. I configured the root, swap and home partition and then, when I'm finished a message appears:

```
"The partition table format in use on your disks normally requires you to
create a separate partition for boot loader code. This partitionshould be 
marked for use as an "EFI boot Partition" and should be at least 35 MB in
size. Note that this is not hte same as a partition mounted on /boot."
```

What I tried, is to make an EFI partition exactly as suggested on this site: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace .
However, the message kept appearing.

How should I proceed if I want to erase everything and leave just the new Ubuntu? Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: You can just choose erase everything and install Ubuntu. The installer will create all partitions correctly for you.

Comment: And before wasting time, check that the hardware is fine. In the two cases it happened to me, the hardware was at fault. [Only once I solved that, through it was not easy, with Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102648/how-to-tell-linux-kernel-3-0-to-completely-ignore-a-failing-disk); the other time I had to trash the laptop.

Comment: @Rmano you're correct. I checked my hard disk, and it is failing and will die soon. So I should replace my disk? Should everything work then?

Comment: For sure it will **not** work with  a failing hard-disk. That will not guarantee that it *will* work with a good disk, but it's a start...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Troubles for Installing ubuntu in HP1000 with Windows to go](http://askubuntu.com/questions/649622/troubles-for-installing-ubuntu-in-hp1000-with-windows-to-go)